# JPanel Inside Of A JPanel

Tags: java, swing, resize, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to get a JPanel to appear inside of another JPanel.  Currently, the JPanel is in an external JFrame and loads with my other JFrame.  I want the JPanel to be inside the other JPanel so the program does not open two different windows.

Here is a picture:

[image: Picture]

The small JPanel with the text logs I want inside of the main game frame.  I've tried adding the panel to the panel, `panel.add(othePanel)`. I've tried adding it the JFrame, `frame.add(otherPanel)`.  It just overwrites everything else and gives it a black background.

How can I add the panel, resize, and move it?

**Edits:**

That is where I want the chatbox to be.

[image: That is where I want the chatbox to be.]

**Class code:**

Left out top of class.

```
public static JPanel panel;
public static JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 30);
public static JTextField userInputField = new JTextField(30);

public static void write(String message) {
    Chatbox.textArea.append("[Game]: " + message + "\n");
    Chatbox.textArea.setCaretPosition(Chatbox.textArea.getDocument()
            .getLength());
    Chatbox.userInputField.setText("");
}

public Chatbox() {
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(220, 40));
    panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(380, 100));
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    scrollPane
            .setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    userInputField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            String fromUser = userInputField.getText();
            if (fromUser != null) {
                textArea.append(Frame.username + ":" + fromUser + "\n");
                textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument()
                        .getLength());
                userInputField.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
    panel.add(userInputField, SwingConstants.CENTER);
    panel.add(scrollPane, SwingConstants.CENTER);

    //JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    //frame.add(panel);
    //frame.setSize(400, 170);
    //frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

**Main frame class:**

```
    public Frame() {
    frame.getContentPane().remove(loginPanel);
    frame.repaint();

    String capName = capitalizeString(Frame.username);
    name = new JLabel(capName);

    new EnemyHealth("enemyhealth10.png");
    new Health("health10.png");
    new LoadRedCharacter("goingdown.gif");
    new Spellbook();
    new LoadMobs();
    new LoadItems();
    new Background();
    new Inventory();
    new ChatboxInterface();

    frame.setBackground(Color.black);
    Frame.redHealthLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    ticks.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    ticks.setForeground(Color.yellow);
    Frame.redHealthLabel.setForeground(Color.black);

    // Inventory slots
    panel.add(slot1);

    panel.add(name);

    name.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    name.setForeground(Color.white);

    panel.add(enemyHealthLabel);
    panel.add(redHealthLabel);
    panel.add(fireSpellBookLabel);
    panel.add(iceSpellBookLabel);
    panel.add(spiderLabel);
    panel.add(appleLabel);
    panel.add(fireMagicLabel);
    panel.add(swordLabel);

    // Character
    panel.add(redCharacterLabel);

    // Interface
    panel.add(inventoryLabel);
    panel.add(chatboxLabel);

    // Background
    panel.add(backgroundLabel);

    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.getContentPane().invalidate();
    frame.getContentPane().validate();
    frame.getContentPane().repaint();

      //I WOULD LIKE THE LOADING OF THE PANEL SOMEWHERE IN THIS CONSTRUCTOR.

    new ResetEntities();
    frame.repaint();

    panel.setLayout(null);
    Run.loadKeyListener();

    Player.px = Connect.x;
    Player.py = Connect.y;

    new Mouse();

    TextualMenu.rect = new Rectangle(Frame.inventoryLabel.getX() + 80,
            Frame.inventoryLabel.getY() + 100,
            Frame.inventoryLabel.getWidth(),
            Frame.inventoryLabel.getHeight());

    Player.startMessage();
}
```

Comment: Your background frame has three separate areas. Where exactly do you want your text logs to appear? Which layout manager are you using for the background frame?

Comment: You're going to need to give more about how you've structured the frame already.

Comment: I have updated my main post with more information.  The background frame has a null layout.

Comment: There's a significant problem right there: you should not be using null layout. Doing this makes creating and maintaining your GUI much more difficult than it has to be. Edit: as Swing expert camickr already points out -- 1+ to him. You are strongly advised to listen to whatever he has to tell you since he knows his Swing very well.

Comment: I've always used null layout.  So I'm going to need to keep it because I need to place certain images at specific areas.  However, there has to be a way to still add JPanels.

Comment: @Nic: I'm guessing that you've always used it because you are not yet fully knowledgeable in use of the standard (and additional) layout managers. Trust me you have no need to use null layout, and also that your coding and this problem will all be much easier solvable if you use layout managers appropriately. That is my experience as a journeyman Swing programmer. I can't speak for your level of Swing competence as I don't know you well, but looking at your code and use of statics, I have to give the edge of knowledge and experience to myself and Rob Camick. Please believe us.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use static variables.

Don't use a null layout.

Use appropriate layout managers. Maybe the main panel uses a BorderLayout. Then you add your main component to the CENTER and a second panel to the EAST. The second panel can also use a BorderLayout. You can then add the two components to the NORTH, CENTER or SOUTH as you require.

Comment: My frame, main panel, and chat panel all use null layout.

Comment: I know. My suggestion is to use Swing properly and to use layout managers.

Comment: That's the problem though.  I need to place my images at specific locations.  Not the generic compass locations.

Comment: Not based on the image you posted. You have components on the left, the top/right and bottom/right. This can easily be done with a layout manager as I have already suggested. Also, there is more than one layout manager you could use if you don't like the current suggestion.

Comment: The apple, spider, hit boxes, character, etc, they are all at coordinate specific locations.

Comment: If you can use layout managers to place images at any desire coordinates, then yes, I'm interested.  If not, I have to stick with null.

Comment: The question is not about placing the apple, spider etc. Those are positioned at random locations so I don't have a problem using a null layout here (although others on the forum do). Your question is about `placing a panel within another panel`. I'm questioning the use of a null layout for your main panel which holds the sub panels. I've said all I can say. As I understand the question, you should be using a layout manager in this specific question.

Comment: The main panel holds all the images.  So if I change my main panels layout manager, I will lose all my images locations.  The only panel that I want added to the main panel is the chat box panel.

Comment: @Nic: your problem is that your assumptions are incorrect. You will not lose any image locations if they are properly placed in component and if the containers that hold the components use proper layout managers. You have to let go of your assumptions and at least try these recommendations. Else what use is giving you advice if you won't listen to us?

Answer (score 1):

For example, using a custom Border:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.RadialGradientPaint;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.AbstractBorder;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FrameEg extends JPanel {
   public static final String FRAME_URL_PATH = "http://th02.deviantart.net/"
         + "fs70/PRE/i/2010/199/1/0/Just_Frames_5_by_ScrapBee.png";
   public static final int INSET_GAP = 120;

   private BufferedImage frameImg;
   private BufferedImage smlFrameImg;

   public FrameEg() {
      try {
         URL frameUrl = new URL(FRAME_URL_PATH);
         frameImg = ImageIO.read(frameUrl);

         final int smlFrameWidth = frameImg.getWidth() / 2;
         final int smlFrameHeight = frameImg.getHeight() / 2;
         smlFrameImg = new BufferedImage(smlFrameWidth, smlFrameHeight,
               BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
         Graphics g = smlFrameImg.getGraphics();
         g.drawImage(frameImg, 0, 0, smlFrameWidth, smlFrameHeight, null);
         g.dispose();

         int top = INSET_GAP;
         int left = top;
         int bottom = top;
         int right = left;
         Insets insets = new Insets(top, left, bottom, right);
         MyBorder myBorder = new MyBorder(frameImg, insets);

         JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(50, 60);
         textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
         textArea.setLineWrap(true);
         for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
            textArea.append("Hello world! How is it going? ");
         }
         setLayout(new BorderLayout(1, 1));
         setBackground(Color.black);

         Dimension prefSize = new Dimension(frameImg.getWidth(),
               frameImg.getHeight());
         JPanel centerPanel = new MyPanel(prefSize);
         centerPanel.setBorder(myBorder);
         centerPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(1, 1));
         centerPanel.add(new JScrollPane(textArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);

         MyPanel rightUpperPanel = new MyPanel(new Dimension(smlFrameWidth,
               smlFrameHeight));
         MyPanel rightLowerPanel = new MyPanel(new Dimension(smlFrameWidth,
               smlFrameHeight));
         top = top / 2;
         left = left / 2;
         bottom = bottom / 2;
         right = right / 2;
         Insets smlInsets = new Insets(top, left, bottom, right);
         rightUpperPanel.setBorder(new MyBorder(smlFrameImg, smlInsets));
         rightUpperPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
         rightLowerPanel.setBorder(new MyBorder(smlFrameImg, smlInsets));
         rightLowerPanel.setBackgroundImg(createBackgroundImg(rightLowerPanel
               .getPreferredSize()));

         JTextArea ruTextArea1 = new JTextArea(textArea.getDocument());
         ruTextArea1.setWrapStyleWord(true);
         ruTextArea1.setLineWrap(true);
         rightUpperPanel.add(new JScrollPane(ruTextArea1), BorderLayout.CENTER);

         JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 1, 1));
         rightPanel.add(rightUpperPanel);
         rightPanel.add(rightLowerPanel);
         rightPanel.setOpaque(false);
         add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
         add(rightPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   private BufferedImage createBackgroundImg(Dimension preferredSize) {
      BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(preferredSize.width,
            preferredSize.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      Point2D center = new Point2D.Float(img.getWidth()/2, img.getHeight()/2); 
      float radius = img.getWidth() / 2;
      float[] dist = {0.0f, 1.0f};
      Color centerColor = new Color(100, 100, 50);
      Color outerColor = new Color(25, 25, 0);
      Color[] colors = {centerColor , outerColor };
      RadialGradientPaint paint = new RadialGradientPaint(center, radius, dist, colors);
      Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
      g2.setPaint(paint);
      g2.fillRect(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
      g2.dispose();

      return img;
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      FrameEg mainPanel = new FrameEg();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameEg");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.setResizable(false);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyPanel extends JPanel {
   private Dimension prefSize;
   private BufferedImage backgroundImg;

   public MyPanel(Dimension prefSize) {
      this.prefSize = prefSize;
   }

   public void setBackgroundImg(BufferedImage background) {
      this.backgroundImg = background;
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      if (backgroundImg != null) {
         g.drawImage(backgroundImg, 0, 0, this);
      }
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return prefSize;
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyBorder extends AbstractBorder {
   private BufferedImage borderImg;
   private Insets insets;

   public MyBorder(BufferedImage borderImg, Insets insets) {
      this.borderImg = borderImg;
      this.insets = insets;
   }

   @Override
   public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width,
         int height) {
      g.drawImage(borderImg, 0, 0, c);
   }

   @Override
   public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
      return insets;
   }
}
```

Which would look like:

[image]